# Simplifying a foreach loop with LINQ (selecting two objects in each iteration)

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following interface and two classes:

```
public interface IMyObj
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyObj1 : IMyObj
{
    public MyObj1(int id) { Id = id; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{GetType().Name} : {Id}";
}

public class MyObj2 : IMyObj
{
    public MyObj2(int id) { Id = id; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{GetType().Name} : {Id}";
}
```

And given following logic that uses them:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 5, 11, 17 };

var list = new List<IMyObj>();

foreach (var n in numbers)
{
    // I'd like to simplify this part with LINQ...
    list.Add(new MyObj1(n));
    list.Add(new MyObj2(n));
}

Assert.AreEqual(8, list.Count);
```

The test passes, and I see inside `list` exactly what I want - two object instances per a number:

```
Count = 8
  [0]: {MyObj1 : 1}
  [1]: {MyObj2 : 1}
  [2]: {MyObj1 : 5}
  [3]: {MyObj2 : 5}
  [4]: {MyObj1 : 11}
  [5]: {MyObj2 : 11}
  [6]: {MyObj1 : 17}
  [7]: {MyObj2 : 17}
```

My question is, how do I simplify the `foreach` loop logic  with LINQ? I'm thinking there might be an elegant way in doing the same with the [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) operator perhaps, but I've not been able to produce the same output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SelectMany` is indeed what you want:

```
var list = numbers.SelectMany(n => new IMyObj[] { new MyObj1(n), new MyObj2(n) })
                  .ToList();
```

In other words, for each number, create a two-element array, which is then flattened using to `SelectMany`.

The `new IMyObj[]` part is required rather than just `new[]` because type inference can't tell what array type you'd want. If the types were the same, you could do something like:

```
var list = numbers.SelectMany(n => new[] { new MyObj(n), new MyObj(n) })
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate two lists using `[Union][1]`:

```
var result = numbers.Select(x => (IMyObj) new MyObj1(x))
    .Union(numbers.Select(x => x => new MyObj2(x)));
```

Alternativly one by one:

```
var l1 = numbers.Select(x => new MyObj1(x)).Cast<IMyObject>().ToList();
var l2 = numbers.Select(x => new MyObj(x));

var result = l1.Concat(l2);
```

Or `l1.AddRange(l2)`.

Of course all those approaches won´t have the same order as your inout as first all instances off `MyObj1` are stored and then all instances of `MyOb2`.

Comment: Note that that doesn't give the same order as the OP's original code, unlike `SelectMany`. I'd also suggest using `Concat` instead of `Union` as set-wise behavior hasn't been specified... and finally, you need to specify type arguments using the interface as otherwise that won't compile.