# How to simplify the multiple foreach using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Here I have provided my sample c# code.

```
foreach (var table in dataSet.Tables)
        {
            foreach (var field in table.Fields)
            {
                if (displayText.Contains(field.Name))
                {
                    displayText = displayText.Replace(field.Name, field.Id);
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone suggest me how to simply this code using linq?

Comment: Maybe this thread could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960889/simplifying-a-foreach-loop-with-linq-selecting-two-objects-in-each-iteration/45960955

Comment: This looks simple & _clean_.

Comment: I guess `table.Fields` should be `table.Columns`. Is `dataSet` a `DataSet`?

Comment: Primary opinion based? In my opinion it is not possible to simplify the code. You can just reduce the number of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible on one line (even if it adds an extra list allocation, but it could be avoided by using a single foreach statement instead of ToList().ForEach() ):

```
dataset.Tables
       .SelectMany(table => table.Fields)
       .Where(field => displayText.Contains(field.Name))
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(field => displayText = displayText.Replace(field.Name, field.Id););
```

Comment: `List.ForEach` not `Foreach`

Comment: This is lower lines, but NO WAY a simplification...

Comment: @swe I had a hard time figuring out you meant *fewer* instead of *lower*

Comment: @Rafalon I'm sorry, i'm no native speaker... my english is quite well, i think, but not perfect... :(

Comment: @swe Me neither ;) And I also make mistakes, so don't worry. My comment was mostly so people reading your comment don't spend too much time understanding it